# Call MPMoviePlayerViewController in app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using story board in app.
Using storyboard all views are connected properly
Now new thing I want to do is,

When my Splash screen goes down, I want to show 3 sec video every time user opens the app.

I know how to load video from viewcontroller,
Following is code that I used to launch the video.

```
- (void)showVideo
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSLog(@"video path :- %@",url);
    videoController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    videoController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoController];
    [videoController.moviePlayer play];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:videoController];
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)_notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:nil];

    [videoController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [videoController.moviePlayer stop];
    videoController = nil;
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

But when I use this code in my rootViewController app crashes saying

```
Attempt to present <MPMoviePlayerViewController:> on <DashbaordVC:> whose view is not in the window hierarchy
```

But when I use same code in other demo app using navigation controller (No Storyboard) it works fine.
But in this app where story board is used, it crashes.

Also I tried

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.videoController animated:NO];
```

Then I thought of adding this code in AppDelegate file and calling the method from `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching`

But didn't help.
can anyone guide me.... for the same
Also how to add `MPMoviePlayerViewController` in app delegate.

Comment: Please add code you are using in the app that causes problem.

Comment: You are calling showVideo method from ViewDidLoad, Right?

Comment: Yes, calling method from ViewDidLoad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this by MPMoviePlayerController. Try following code

```
         NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"];
         NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

        videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
        [videoPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, viewTopbar.frame.size.height,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - (viewTopbar.frame.size.height + 50.0))];
                [videoPlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];

        [videoPlayer setContentURL:url];
        [videoPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
        [videoPlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeNone];
        [videoPlayer prepareToPlay];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:videoPlayer];

       [self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
       [videoPlayer play];
```

And if you dont want full screen then used it like this

```
[videoPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
```

Comment: :- Same code is working for iOS 8.1 but my app is crashing on 8.3. does there any changes for 8.3

Comment: crash when you click on video??

Comment: No, I don't want click on video. I want to launch it as soon as splash screen goes down. So I added this code in rootviewcontroller and called showVideo method from ViewDidLoad

Comment: I guess, I am getting this issue from Navigation, as the code uses storyboard for navigation and issue that I am getting is something like
Attempt to present <MPMoviePlayerViewController:> on <*> whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Comment: you don't need to present this you just simple add this in view as subviews and when didfinish called remove the view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76546/discussion-between-chirag-shah-and-stallone).